# Client for Microsoft Networks service under network adapter no longer needed to access file shares?

Tags: network-share, windows-10

I was troubleshooting a Wi-Fi connectivity issue today when I decided to disable the Client for Microsoft Networks service on the Wi-Fi adapter.

I expected NOT to be able to access the mapped network drive after I disabled it, but for some reason I can still access it.

Does anyone know why?

My network drive (drive letter Z:) is mapped to a file share on my domain controller using the FQDN, and my DNS server resolves to the domain controller correctly.

I am not using NetBIOS over TCP/IP (NBT). I am using Windows 10.